# How to retrieve rows using datetime (python & mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, database, datetime

This is my code:

```
now  = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
curs.execute("SELECT name, msgDate,  FROM test where msgDate=%s",(now))
```

I got these msgs:

```
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 220, in _process_params
  res = list(map(to_mysql,res))
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\projectse\Email\src\a.py", line 65, in <module>
    curs.execute("SELECT name, msgDate FROM messages where msgDate=%s",(now))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 300, in execute
    stmt = operation % self._process_params(params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 225, in _process_params
  "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % e)
  mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: -1: Failed processing format-parameters; 
  'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace:

```
curs.execute("SELECT name, msgDate, FROM test where msgDate=%s",(now))
```

with:

```
curs.execute("SELECT name, msgDate, FROM test where msgDate=%s",%(now))
```

and use this for your time variable:

```
import time
now=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Try seeing what now = `str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))` looks like in the python interpreter, if you're curious why that's a problem.

Comment: OK, I think I actually see what you're problem is not. datetime.datetime.now() looks like datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 7, 19, 36, 5, 977972) right now, which doesn't play nicely with SQL dates, I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   now = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
   now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')


    curs.execute("SELECT name, msgDate,  FROM test where msgDate=:now",dict(now=str(now))

    please try converting date to string format and execute
```